# Cordova plugin InAppBrowser does not open a second time

Tags: cordova, oauth, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm working on a project using Ionic Framework and Phonegap. I need to use OAuth 2.0 for authentication on my app. When I try to login, the app opens an InAppBrowser window inside the Cordova WebView and loads the consent page. Everything works fine until then.

The problem lies when I close the window and try to open it again, it simply doesn't open! What could it be?

This is in my controllers.js file:

```js
var ref = $window.open(oauthUrl, "_self", "location=yes");

ref.addEventListener("loadstart", function () {
  // ...
  // do some logic
  // ...

  ref.close();
  $state.go("login");
});

ref.addEventListener("exit", function () {
  ref.close(); 
  $state.go("index");
  $window.location.reload();      
});
```

I've already tried to remove the `ref.close()` lines, put `ref.show()`, but none of these work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use `_self`, it replaces your content with the oauthUrl content, so cordova.js won't exist and you won't be able to use cordova APIs anymore

use `_blank` instead

Comment: Thank you! Using `_blank` solved a lot of problems for me. But an odd thing : before you answer me, I was testing with `_self`, and I noticed that when I build the app singned for release, the problem I mentioned doesn't happen anymore. Now with `_blank` I don't need to build a release package to be sure that it's working.